# java.io.NotSerializableException: org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml

Tags: jenkins, groovy

i have common Library which print variables from the yml file.

```
       def getHelmSvc(Map helmSvc,String mservice){
                def domain = helmSvc[mservice].domain
                def microservice_name = helmSvc[mservice].microservice_name
                def ingress_required = helmSvc[mservice].ingress_required
                def var_map = [:]
                var_map['microservice_name'] = microservice_name
                var_map['ingress_required'] = ingress_required
                return var_map

        }
```

i am calling above Library in jenkinsfile:

```
         text1=new File('/jenkins/workspace/helm/helm_svc.yml').text

                    Yaml yaml = new Yaml()
                    def obj = yaml.load(text1)

                    ret=getHelmSvc(obj, mservice)
                    println ret
```

it's printing map of variables from yml on console, later am trying to print those values into txt file using shell, it's failing with Serialization issue.

Basically it's printing on console like this:

```
          {microservice_name=some-processor, ingress_required=false}
```

Later am using shell to print to text file, it's were failing with serialization issue.

```
          sh("""
                      echo "$ret" >  "/jenkins/workspace/helm/map.txt"
          """)
```

Error:

```
           an exception which occurred:
in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv.locals
in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv@2b3f4d48
in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CallEnv.caller
in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallEnv@2ee0ffec
in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.e
in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable@108a4042
in field org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.program
in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread@28b2f39d
in field org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.threads
in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@1a7da7eb
in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@1a7da7eb
        Caused: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml
```

if we use above shell command in another script level it works, it's failing only if we add in same script level where loading yaml file.

"**mservice=some-service**", provided as pipeline parameter.

Basically we have file called /jenkins/workspace/helm/helm_svc.yml, it has bunch of variables defined in the map

```
      processor-create:
        microservice_name: processor-create
        service_required: true
        ingress_required: false
      processor-update:
        microservice_name: processor-update
        service_required: true
        ingress_required: false
        scheduler_required: false
      service-create:
        microservice_name: service-create
        service_required: true
        ingress_required: true
        scheduler_required: false
```

i am trying to provide input from pipeline parameter(ex: processor-create) based on that it will get the values from above a file and assign to `ret` variable then we need to print that ret variable value into text file, so that i will provide that text file to ansible playbook in the same stage.

Comment: just search `java.io.NotSerializableException jenkins pipeline`

Comment: Why you use sh to write a file when with groovy its so easy as new File("jenkins/workspace/helm/map.txt").text = "$ret" ?

Comment: @JorgeAguileraGonzalez, you mean $ret value it will print into jenkins/workspace/helm/map.txt file? if we use File method?

Comment: @JorgeAguileraGonzalez updated more information....

Comment: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'File' found among steps [ansiColor, ansiblePlaybook, ansibleVault, archive, bat, build, catchError, checkout, deleteDir, dir,

Comment: did you instance a "new" File ?  I mean you need to write `new File('jenkins/workspace/helm/map.txt').text = "$ret"`

Comment: @JorgeAguileraGonzalez ret=getHelmSvc(obj, mservice)
                        println ret


                        new File("jenkins/workspace/helm/map.txt").text = "$ret"
Still has an issue:

No such field found: field java.io.File text.

Comment: So above File method supposed to print $ret value into "jenkins/workspace/helm/map.txt" file right?

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue until adding `@NonCPS` to a function returning result from Yaml().

This resource was helpful:

> By design a pipeline can only keep records of Serializable objects.
> If you still need to keep an intermediate variable with a non serializable object, you need to extract it into a method and annotate this method with @NonCPS.

https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/230612967-Pipeline-The-pipeline-even-if-successful-ends-with-java-io-NotSerializableException

Discovered as suggested by the comment from dagget.